# Writing parser in Rust - peeking two chars ahead

Tags: parsing, iterator, rust, peek

I'm working on a parser in Rust. The goal is to parse into an AST and then use serde to serialize the AST into JSON.

The DSL that I'm going to parse is semi-similar to JavaScript, but much simpler.

```
pub struct Parser<'a> {
    source: Peekable<str::Chars<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Parser<'a> {
    pub fn new(source: &str) -> Parser {
        Parser {
            source: source.chars().peekable(),
        }
    }

    pub fn parse(&mut self) -> Resource {
        let mut entities = Map::new();

        self.skip_ws();

        loop {
            let entity = self.get_entity();
            entities.insert(entity.id, entity);
            self.skip_ws();
        }
        Resource(entities)
    }

    fn get_entity(&mut self) {
        let id = self.get_identifier();
        self.skip_line_ws();

        if !self.next_char('=') {
            panic!();
        }

        self.bump();

        self.skip_line_ws();

        let value = self.get_pattern();

        if self.next_char('[') && self.next_char('[', 1) {
           // get attributes
           // return entity with attributes
        } else {
           // return entity without attributes
        }
    }
}
```

In two cases, peeking only one character is not sufficient to identify which token I'm collecting. For example, if the peeked character is '[', and the next after it is '[', then it's not part of the entity, but if it's a '[' and then *not* '[', it's an attribute.

I know that in theory I can use `next()` to collect a character and then use `peek()` to look into the next one, but that poses a problem when you identify that the result is not part of the Entity, because in that case, I'd like to move the pointer back one character, and return.

That also doesn't solve the problem in the scenario where I need to peek 3 characters ahead.

It seems to me that I either need ability to peek two chars ahead, or I need an ability to advance the iterator and then move it back.
I found `multipeek` in Itertools that claim to allow for peeking multiple characters ahead, but I don't know how to fit it into my parser.
Can someone guide me or point out at a different approach?

Comment: *but I don't know how to fit it into my parser* — the same way you would with `Peekable`, just using `Multipeek` instead.

Comment: The code example you have provided is not a [MCVE] (emphasis on *C* and *M*, here). Specifically, it's missing key pieces like the implementation of `next_char`, `skip_ws`, `get_identifier`, `get_pattern`, `skip_line_ws`, the definitions of `Resource`, `Map`, etc.

Comment: Are you committed to keeping a chars iterator for the data? In that case you have access to the whole string, and can use it for lookahead (I'd do that without the peekable). For example: `chars_iter.as_str().starts_with("[[")`. Only if you want to use generic iterators for data, do you need to find another soln.